# Valgrind reporting race condition when it should not be

Tags: c++, c, linux, valgrind, race-condition

I tested an application for race conditions with the `helgrind` tool from `Valgrind`. But it reported a race for a code which is protected by a lock. Is `Valgrind` falsely reporting this as race condition, or am I missing something. The code is given below.

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&G_Memory->lock_array[pb->exp_lock_index]);

    pb->subtree_cost += b->subtree_cost;
    pb->interaction_synch += 1; // <--- race here (cost_zones.c:91)

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&G_Memory->lock_array[pb->exp_lock_index]);
```

`Valgrind/Helgrind` reports the following

```
==29768== Possible data race during read of size 8 at 0x56bf8e0 by thread #4
==29768==    at 0x404C51: ComputeSubTreeCosts (cost_zones.c:91)
          ...................
==29768==  This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #1
==29768==    at 0x404C5F: ComputeSubTreeCosts (cost_zones.c:91)
          ...................
```

Comment: Are both threads actually locking the same mutex, or are you trying to lock different ones? It isn't clear whether `pb->exp_lock_index` is the same in both threads.

Comment: @Zeta, i think that if `pb->exp_lock_index` is different between threads, then also `pb->interaction_sync` is

Comment: @DavideBerra: `struct example{ mutex mtx; int &value; example(int&v) : value(v){}}; int myVal; example pb1(myVal), pb2(myVal);`. Both `pb.value` are using the same value `myVal`, but they have different mutexes. So the solution depends on OP's data structure and whether he uses the same mutex.

Comment: David Berra is right. For this program at least, the design is like that. So my question is, can Valgrind report false results?

Comment: But if you are using the same data, but different mutexes, you have got a data race!

Answer (score 2):

From what you've described in the comments, you're missing something. You have a race condition here, because the threads are using different mutexes. Your threads must use the same mutex here, so that the code only executes when they've obtained the one and only lock.